# Overlay the content of html file into another html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any possibility of Overlaying the content of the inside html with others.

For example I have two html files in different folders but in same root.

HTML1:

```
<section>
<div class="html1"></div>
<section>
```

HTML2:

```
<section>
<div class="html2"></div>
<section>
```

Now on click of the button I need to show the content of html2 as an overlay and again on click of the same button I need to hide the html2.

Can anyone let me know how to achieve this.

Comment: why not display none current and display block your next element?

Comment: I think you are looking for this approach : http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I wrote this some time back, but I think it's a solution for your question - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/4qNJu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do not know why you need this, but you can do this :-)

```
<input id="b" type="button" value="button" />
<section id="container" style="width:400px;height:200px;border:1px solid;font-family:Verdana"></section>
<script>
    var button = document.getElementById('b');
    var section = document.getElementById('container');
    var path = ['html_document1.html', 'html_document2.html']; //paths for your documents

    function fu() {
        var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xml.addEventListener('readystatechange', function () {
            if (this.readyState === 4 & this.status === 200) {
                section.innerHTML = this.response;
            }
        }, false);
        var shuffler = path.shift();
        path.push(shuffler);
        xml.open('GET', shuffler, true);
        xml.send(null);
    }
    window.addEventListener('load', fu, false);
    button.addEventListener('click', fu, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it like this

```
<input id="b" type="button" value="button" />
<section id="container" style="width:400px;height:200px;border:1px solid;font-family:Verdana">
    <iframe id="ifr" style="width:100%;height:100%;border:none"></iframe>
</section>
<script>
    var button = document.getElementById('b');
    var section = document.getElementById('container');
    var ifr = document.getElementById('ifr');
    var path = ['html_document1.html', 'html_document2.html']; //paths for your documents
    function fu() {
        var shuffler = path.shift();
        path.push(shuffler);
        ifr.src = shuffler;
    }
    window.addEventListener('load', fu, false);
    button.addEventListener('click', fu, false);
</script>
```